# pig ignores maxReducers and uses mapred.reduce.tasks instead

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

My pig script generates some 5 MR-jobs.
When it starts executing, pig prints:

```
 BytesPerReducer=1000000000 maxReducers=999
```

and continues to create an MR-job with just a single reducer:

```
 Neither PARALLEL nor default parallelism is set for this job. Setting number of reducers to 1
```

BUT, for later jobs generated from the same script, it doesn't print this line, and in one of them it creates `mapred.reduce.tasks` reducers, which in my cluster's case is 4992.

Is this a known bug? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your pig script:

```
SET pig.exec.reducers.max 4000
```

[Read this for more information.](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/api/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/executionengine/mapReduceLayer/InputSizeReducerEstimator.html)